# Getting 400's from aws ELB hostcheck to work with django ALLOWED_HOSTS in aws ECS under awsvpc networking mode?

Tags: django, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

When moving over to ECS with awsvpc networking mode, my ALB says all my hosts are unhealthy because checking `/status/` yields 400s. I've narrowed it down to the issue being something wrong with ALLOWED_HOSTS.

How do I get my web app to give 200's to the ELB Healthchecker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to add the LB's address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`:

```
ELB_HEALTHCHECK_HOSTNAMES = [ip for network in 
    requests.get(os.environ['ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI']).json()['Networks']
    for ip in network['IPv4Addresses']]
ALLOWED_HOSTS += ELB_HEALTHCHECK_HOSTNAMES
```

This will take every IP from every networks attached to your container and add it to your ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Prior to moving over to ECS with awsvpc networking mode, a lot of us are familiar with this line that retrieves the EC2 instance's IP which is used as the hostname by the ELB health checker:

```
ELB_HEALTHCHECK_HOSTNAME = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', timeout=2).text
```

This line under ECS with awsvpc networking retrieves the IP of the EC2 instance, not the ENI attached to your container. To retrieve the IP of the ENI, you send a request to the endpoint in the environment variable ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI}

This returns useful metadata about the containers, including the IPV4

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3.html

Answer (score 11):

Another simple solution would be to write a custom `MIDDLEWARE` which will give the response to ELB before the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is checked.

The middleware can be as simple as:

`project/app/middleware.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class HealthCheckMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META["PATH_INFO"] == "/ping/":
            return HttpResponse("pong")
```

`settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Django Middleware reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: I find this solution much more elegant than adding the hosts to the ALLOWED_HOSTS

Answer (score 3):

You can try this simple method

```
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname

# This environment variable is automatically set when ECS runs a task
if os.environ.get("AWS_EXECUTION_ENV"):
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(gethostbyname(gethostname()))
```